# How to filter out nodes with rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am using the R rvest library to read an html page containing tables.
Unfortunately the tables have inconsistent number of columns.

Here is an example of the table I read:

```
<table>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="hidden">3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="tr0 close notule">
        <td colspan="9">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my code to read the table in R:

```
require(rvest)
url = "table.html"
x <- read_html(url)
(x %>% html_nodes("table")) %>% html_table(fill=T)
# [[1]]
  # X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
# 1  1  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 2  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

I would like to avoid considering the td of class hidden and the tr of class 'tr0 close notule', so that I ony get a table as follows:

```
  X1 X2
   1  2
```

Is there a way to do that with rvest?

Comment: try this. `x %>% html_nodes("table .alt :not(.hidden)")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `xml_remove()`, you can literally remove those nodes

```
text <- '<table>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="hidden">3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="tr0 close notule">
        <td colspan="9">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>'

html_tree <- read_html(text)

#select nodes you want to remove
hidden_nodes <- html_tree %>%
    html_nodes(".hidden")
close_nodes <- html_tree %>%
    html_nodes(".tr0.close.notule")

#remove those nodes
xml_remove(hidden_nodes)
xml_remove(close_nodes)


html_tree %>%
    html_table()
```

I examined the css and found that the css for those nodes are like: `tr0 close notule`,`tr1 close notule`,...,`tr{n} close notule`, so you need to be more general to select all those nodes

### Edit code to make it work with the real website:

```
library(purrr)
library(rvest)

my_session <- html_session("https://www.zone-turf.fr/cheval/greaty-lion-592958/")

#select all table nodes
tables <- my_session %>%
    html_nodes(".inner2 > table")

# remove nodes with class of "close and notule"
close_nodes <- tables %>%
    html_nodes(".close.notule")
xml_remove(close_nodes)

#use map to create all tables and store them in a list.
map(tables,~ .x %>% html_table())
```

After adjusting the css selector for nodes to remove, it should work:

```
#sample output --------------
[[8]]
RangRg        Cheval S/A CordeC PoidsPds      Jockey Cote   Ecart   
1      1        Latita  F2      3     57,5  T. Piccone  6.3 1'56"05 NA
2      2 Youmzain Star  M2      6       59    F. Veron  4.7     3/4 NA
3      3      Pharrell  M2      1       59 J.B. Eyquem  1.9       1 NA
4      4   King Bubble  M2      4       58   N. Perret 15.5       1 NA
5      5     Dark Side  M2      5       57  A. Hamelin 12.4       8 NA
6      6   Greaty Lion  F2      2     57,5  F. Blondel  6.8      15 NA

[[9]]
  RangRg             Cheval S/A CordeC PoidsPds      Jockey Cote   Ecart     
1      1        Marianafoot  M2      4       59   N. Perret  2.1 1'40"25 lire
2      2 Ballet de la Reine  F2      2       54 H. Journiac  3.4   1 1/2     
3      3        Greaty Lion  F2      5     57,5  F. Blondel  7.0       2     
4      4      Beau Massagot  M2      6       54  E. Cieslik  9.7       5     
5      5        London Look  M2      3       58  T. Piccone  8.8     5,5     
6      6       Spirit Louve  F2      1       53   L. Grosso 18.8    Tête     

[[10]]
   RangRg          Cheval S/A CordeC PoidsPds        Jockey Cote    Ecart   
1       1     Greaty Lion  F2     12       58    F. Blondel  3.6  1'43"84 NA
2       2         Maeghan  F2     11       58     G. Millet  5.1        1 NA
3       3 Neige Eternelle  F2      8       58    A. Roussel  3.8    1 3/4 NA
4       4    Fair la Joie  F2      9       58     G. Congiu 11.6      1/4 NA
5       5     Nicky Green  F2      7       58     R. Thomas  6.4      1/4 NA
6       6   Coral Slipper  F2      5       58  A. Fouassier 28.4    1 1/4 NA
7       7  Gaia de Cerisy  F2     13       58      D. Breux 32.5        1 NA
8       8      Luna Riska  F2      1       58 N. Larenaudie 58.3 Encolure NA
9       9   Belle Vendome  F2      2       56  A. Teissieux 49.9    2 1/2 NA
10      0     Rebel Dream  F2      3       58      S. Leger 56.6          NA
11      0      Facinateur  F2      4       56      M. Berto 21.2          NA
12      0        Giovanna  F2     10       56    F. Garnier 27.8          NA
```

Comment: Thank you. It works on the small example, but somehow it does not work on the real life case I have, which has the url https://www.zone-turf.fr/cheval/greaty-lion-592958/

Comment: Hi, I just adjusted my answer to make it work with the real website.