# Remove a child node by class name with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm scraping a forum and extracting the post nodes, getting something like this:

```
nodes = page %>% html_nodes('.mypost')

nodes[[1]]
<div class="mypost" itemprop="text">
    <div class="bbcode_container">
        <div class="bbcode_quote">
            <div class="quote_container">
            <div class="bbcode_quote_container b-icon b-icon__ldquo-l--gray"></div>
                <div class="bbcode_postedby">
                    Originally posted by <strong>Mike</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                    This is great news. Can you elaborate on what it means? \
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    I copied this from another web site. So I'm not sure...
</div>
```

I want to get all the text within the posts (in this case for node 1 the "I copied this...") but remove everything that is within the div class="bbcode_container".

Is there a way to remove children based on the class name? It's possible my node might have other div children with other names, and the position of bbcode_container is not fixed (could be anywhere, not at all, or appear multiple times so an xpath approach seems tricky at best).

I've seen there's a way to negate within rvest but I'm certain I'm doing it wrong:

```
nodes %>% html_nodes(':not(.bbcode_container)') %>% html_text()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768364/how-to-filter-out-nodes-with-rvest/50769954

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter out nodes with rvest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768364/how-to-filter-out-nodes-with-rvest)